# ansible-playbook 2.5 doesn't find group vars when specifying an inventory file directly

Tags: ansible-playbook

I've been using ansible scripts for some one shot tasks, for example doing a firstsetup after provisioning a VM.

I have a script that creates a temporary inventory file, uses it to run an ansible playbook and deletes the temporary file afterwards:

```sh
INVENTORY=$(mktemp /tmp/inst-inventory.XXXXXX)
echo "[$FLAVOR]" > $INVENTORY
echo "$HOSTNAME user_password='$USER_PASSWORD' admin_password='$ADMIN_PASSWORD'" >> $INVENTORY
ansible-playbook -i $INVENTORY `dirname $0`/firstsetup_$FLAVOR.yml --become
rm $INVENTORY
```

This worked perfectly, but since upgrading ansible from 2.4 to 2.5 the playbooks can't find variables defined in the `group_vars` directory anymore.

```
$ playbooks/firstsetup.sh HOSTNAME ubuntu
Password for localadmin: PASSWORD

Running ansible-playbook firstsetup_ubuntu.yml on HOSTNAME

PLAY [ubuntu] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************
fatal: [HOSTNAME]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'become_pass' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ubuntu_inisc_initialpass' is undefined"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/geschnei/playbooks/firstsetup_ubuntu.retry

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************
HOSTNAME                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

This `undefined variable` is defined in `~/.ansible/group_vars/ubuntu.yml` and is found when I run the same playbook against a host that is listed in the regular inventory file.

The [Roadmap for Ansible 2.5](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/roadmap/ROADMAP_2_5.html) lists:

> Add option to set playbook dir for adhoc, inventory and console to allow for ‘relative path loading’

Which sounds like it could be related, but I am unable to find more specific information about it. The [2.5 Porting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html) doesn't mention anything about that either.

What do I have to configure so ansible-playbook finds the `group_vars` files again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downgrading ansible to 2.4 I had to realize that it didn't work with that version either.

More reading revealed that it is [not possible to change the location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25364346/212107) of `host_vars` or `group_vars`, they are always relative to the `hostfile`.

So after all I solved it by changing the location of the temporary inventory to the `~/.ansible` dir, where the regular inventory also resides.

```bash
INVENTORY=$(mktemp ~/.ansible/inst-inventory.XXXXXX)
```

I don't know why it worked before. It works again now.